# Trouble with recursive text splitting

Tags: python, regex, string, parsing, recursion

trying to split text via text-defined boundary markers using recursion and create a list of lists and strings containing all of the organized parts of the original text file.

The split isn't happening.

Here is the short version: The real problem script:

```
def separate(text,boundary = None):
    if boundary == None:
        m = re.findall(r'(?<=boundary=).*',text)
        i = 0
        while i < len(m): #have all levels of Boundary/headers named
            boundary = m[i]
            textList = recursiveSplit(text,boundary)
            i += 1
        pdb.set_trace()
        return textList

def recursiveSplit(chunk,boundary):
    if type(chunk) is types.StringType:
        ar = re.split(r'(?P<boundary>)(?!--)',chunk)
        return ar
    if type(chunk) is types.ListType:
        i = 0
        while i < len(chunk):
            chunk[i] = recursiveSplit(chunk[i],boundary)
            i += 1
        return obj
```

I've posted this script before and people wanted me to post it in its entirety so I'll do that

```
  #Textbasics email parser
#based on a "show original" file converted into text

from sys import argv
import re, os, pdb, types

script, filename = argv
text = open(filename).read()
type = "text only" #Set the default type of email

#cut the email up by sections
#--A section is defined as any time there are two line breaks in a row
textList = re.split(r"\n\n", text)
header = textList[0]
if re.search(r'MIME-Version',header):
    type = "MIME"

# If mail has no attachments, parse as a text-only email
class Parser(object):

    def __init__(self,textList):
        a = 1
        self.body = ""
        self.textList = textList
        self.header = textList[0]
        while a < len(textList):
            self.body = self.body + textList[a] + '\n\n'
            a += 1

        m = re.search(r'(?<=Subject: ).*', self.header)
        self.subject = m.group(0)

        m = re.search(r'(?<=From: ).*', self.header)
        self.fromVar = m.group(0)

        m = re.search(r'(?<=To: ).*', self.header)
        self.toVar = m.group(0)

        m = re.search(r'(?<=Date: )\w+\s\w+\s\w+', self.header)
        self.date = m.group(0)

    def returnParsed(self,descriptor = "all"):
        if descriptor == "all":
            retv = "Subject: " + self.subject + "\n" + "From: " + self.fromVar + "\n" + "To: " + self.toVar + "\n" + "Date: " + self.date + "\n" + "\n" + self.body
            return retv

        if descriptor == "subject":
            return self.subject
        if descriptor == "fromVar":
            return self.fromVar
        if descriptor == "toVar":
            return self.toVar
        if descriptor == "date":
            return self.date
        if descriptor == "body":
            return self.body

class MIMEParser(Parser):

    class MIMEDataDecoder(object):
        def __init__(self,decodeString,type):
            pass    


    def __init__(self,textList):
        self.textList = textList
        self.nestedItems = []
        newItem = NestedItem(self)
        newItem.setContentType("Header")
        newItem.setValue(self.textList[0])
        self.nestedItems.append(newItem)
        if re.search(r'(boundary=)',newItem.value):
            helperItem = NestedItem(self)
            helperItem.value = (self.textList[0])
            m = re.search(r'(?<=Content-Type: ).+(?=;)',newItem.value)
            helperItem.setContentType(m.group(0))
            self.nestedItems.append(helperItem)

        self.organizeData()   
        """i = 0
        while i < len(self.textList):
            newItem = NestedItem(self)
            ct = self.nextContentType
            newItem.setContentType(ct)
            newItem.setValue(self.textList[i])
            self.nestedItems.append(newItem)
            m = re.search(r'(?<=Content-Type: ).+(?=;)',self.textList[i])
            if m:
                self.nextContentType = m.group(0)
            i += 1
            """

    def nestItem (self,item):
        self.nestedItems.append(item)

    def organizeData(self):
        self.nestLevel = 1
        self.currentSuper = self
        m = re.search(r'(?<=boundary=).*',self.textList[0])
        self.currentBoundary = m.group(0)
        self.currentList = self.textList
        self.currentList.remove(self.textList[0])
        self.formerObjectDatabase = {}
        pdb.set_trace()
        while self.nestLevel > 0:
            i = 0
            while i < len(self.currentList):

                boundary = self.currentBoundary
                #If block is a "normal block", containing a current boundary identifier
                p = re.search(r'--(?P<boundary>)(?!--)', text)
                if p:
                    newItem = NestedItem(self.currentSuper)
                    newItem.setValue(self.currentList[i])
                    r = re.search(r'(?<=Content-Type: ).+(?=;)',newItem.value)
                    if r:
                        newItem.setContentType(r.group(0))
                    self.currentObject = newItem
                    self.currentSuper.nestItem(self.currentObject)
                #If the block contains a new block boundary
                m = re.search(r'(?<=boundary=).*',self.currentList[i])
                if m:
                    #begin new layer of recursive commands
                    newFormerObject = self.FormerCurrentObject(self.currentList,self.currentSuper,self.currentBoundary)
                    self.formerObjectDatabase[self.nestLevel] = newFormerObject
                    self.currentSuper = self.currentObject
                    self.nestLevel += 1
                    self.currentBoundary = m.group(0)
                    boundary = self.currentBoundary
                    #self.currentList = re.split(r'--(?P<boundary>)(?!--)', self.currentList[i])
                boundary = self.currentBoundary
                #If block contains an "end of boundary" marker
                q = re.search(r'(?P<boundary>)--', text)
                if q:
                    self.nestLevel -= 1
                    currentObject = self.formerObjectDatabase[self.nestLevel]
                    self.currentList = currentObject.formerList
                    self.currentSuper = currentObject.formerSuper
                    self.currentBoundary = currentObject.formerBoundary
                i += 1                    


    class FormerCurrentObject:
        def __init__(self,formerList,formerSuper,formerBoundary):
            self.formerList = formerList
            self.formerSuper = formerSuper
            self.formerBoundary = formerBoundary




    def printAll(self):
        print "printing all: %d" % len(self.nestedItems)
        i = 0
        while i < len(self.nestedItems):
            print "printing out item %d" % i
            self.nestedItems[i].printOut()
            i += 1

class NestedItem(object):
    def __init__(self,superObject,contentType=" ",value = " "):
        self.superObject = superObject
        self.contentType = contentType
        self.value = value
        self.nestedItems = []

    def nestItem(self,item):
        self.nestedItems.append(item)

    def printOut(self,printBuffer = ""):
        print printBuffer + '++%s' % self.contentType
        print printBuffer + self.value
        a = 0
        printBuffer = printBuffer + "  "
        while a < len(self.nestedItems):
            self.nestedItems[a].printOut(printBuffer)

    def setContentType(self,contentType):
        self.contentType = contentType

    def setValue(self,value):
        self.value = value



if type == "text only":
    p = Parser(textList)
    print p.returnParsed()
# ---PROBLEM CODE STARTS HERE---
def separate(text,boundary = None):
    pdb.set_trace()
    if boundary == None:
        m = re.findall(r'(?<=boundary=).*',text)
        i = 0
        textList = [text]
        while i < len(m): #have all levels of Boundary/headers named
            boundary = m[i]
            textList = recursiveSplit(textList,boundary)
            i += 1

    return textList

def recursiveSplit(chunk,boundary):
    if type(chunk) is types.ListType: #<<--error occurs here
        for obj in chunk:
            recursiveSplit(obj,boundary)
    if type(chunk) is types.StringType:
        list = re.split(r'(?P<boundary>)(?!--)',chunk)
        return list
    return None
#---PROBLEM CODE ENDS(?) HERE---

if type == "MIME":
    #separate the text file instead by its boundary identifier
    p = MIMEParser(separate(text))
    p.printAll()
```

You can use any MIME type email for this to run. Here's the one I've been using for convenience

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Received: by 10.112.170.40 with HTTP; Fri, 3 May 2013 05:08:21 -0700 (PDT)
Date: Fri, 3 May 2013 08:08:21 -0400
Delivered-To: MYEMAIL@gmail.com
Message-ID: <@mail.gmail.com>
Subject: MiB 5/3/13 7:43AM (EST)
From: ME<MYEMAIL@gmail.com>
To: SOMEONE <SOMEONE@aol.com>
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=BNDRY1

--BNDRY1
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=BNDRY2

--BNDRY2
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1

-changed signature methods to conform more to working clinic header
methods(please test/not testable in simulator)
-confirmed that signature image is showing up in simulator. Awaiting
further tests
-Modified findings spacing/buffer. See if you like it

--BNDRY2
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1

<div dir="ltr">-changed signature methods to conform more to working clinic header methods(please test/not testable in simulator)<div style>-confirmed that signature image is showing up in simulator. Awaiting further tests</div>
<div style>-Modified findings spacing/buffer. See if you like it</div></div>

--BNDRY2--
--BNDRY1
Content-Type: application/zip; name="Make it Brief.ipa.zip"
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="Make it Brief.ipa.zip"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
X-Attachment-Id: f_hg9biuno0

<<FILE DATA>>
--BNDRY1--
```

Comment: What is the final output you are hoping to get?

Comment: I'm hoping to get a list of both lists and strings that are separated by the BOUND markings. so each list element would start with BNDRY(X) and then contain only the information underneath that BNDRY heading

Comment: I figured out that the regex is not correct. When I hardcode BNDRY1 it works as expected (for BNDRY1).

Comment: It's worth mentioning that the `recursiveSplit` function at the top of your question doesn't match the one in the full script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was in the regex. There may be a cooler way to do it, but I just created a search string literal based off of the variables.

```
def recursiveSplit(chunk,boundary):
    if type(chunk) is types.StringType:
        #ar = re.split(r'(?P<boundary>)(?!--)',chunk)
        searchString = "--%s" % boundary
        print searchString
        ar = re.split(searchString,chunk)
        return ar
    if type(chunk) is types.ListType:
        i = 0
        while i < len(chunk):
            chunk[i] = recursiveSplit(chunk[i],boundary)
            i += 1
        return obj
```